# What is the recommended method of loading data once to user everywhere around the app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

As almost every project has some predefined setting values which are to be used throughout the application, what is the recommended way of loading them once and then using everywhere?

For example, I did a project where I had some settings stored in the database which were accessed throughout the application. Rather than querying them each and every time, I was loading everything into a static class and then would use that throughout the application. What other approach do you use?

Comment: You could inject a factory like `ISettingsProvider` into classes that need those settings. Then you could use an implementation that retrieves the settings and caches them in memory to return the same instance instead of reloading them. You could even just inject the settings class where needed and configure the container to resolve `ISettingsProvider`, and then make the settings class it returns a singleton.

Comment: You can also create a custom config provider that reads from a database. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration#create-an-entity-framework-custom-provider

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class that retrieves your settings from the database:

```
public class SqlSettingsProvider : ISettingsProvider
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public SqlSettingsProvider(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public Settings GetSettings()
    {
        // load the settings from SQL
    }
}
```

You can register that class with your `ServiceCollection`:

```
var connectionString = "xyz"; // load this from config;
services.AddSingleton<SqlSettingsProvider>(provider => 
    new SqlSettingsProvider(connectionString));
```

(You could have an interface like `ISettingsProvider`, but in this example it's not needed, because you're going to inject `Settings`, not the settings provider.)

Then, configure your service collection to resolve `Settings` by resolving `SqlSettingsProvider` and using it to retrieve an instance of `Settings`.

```
services.AddSingleton<Settings>(provider => 
    provider.GetService<SqlSettingsProvider>().GetSettings());
```

Now wherever you need `Settings` you just inject them:

```
public class SomeControllerOrOtherClass
{
    private readonly Settings _settings;

    public SomeControllerOrOtherClass(Settings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }
}
```

Now your classes can just depend on `Settings` and not care where it comes from. The service collection will only create it once and will then return the same instance each time, meaning it only gets looked up once from the database.

There could be some long-term benefit to injecting an interface like `ISettingsProvider` instead. That gives you a little bit more flexibility. For example, instead of storing the `Settings` for the lifetime of the application it could cache them for specified duration, or it could behave differently in some other way.